# couldn't find file 'jquery-ui' i get this error even after having this file in my application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to add a jquery ui datepicker to my application and getting this error 
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
  (in /home/sumyvps/rails_projects/Expense_book/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:18)

I tried instructions in many links but not getting the solution to this.

my Gemfile is as

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'

group :development, :test do
 gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
 gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
 gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
 gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
 gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

application.css file is as below

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
*= require jquery.ui.core
*= require jquery.ui.theme
```

application.js is as

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

someone please help...

Comment: The first thing I noticed is the back tick in `//= require jquery` in your `application.js`.  Is that just a typo in this question or is that how it is in your code?

Comment: That is just a typo in question...its not there in code...

Comment: Fixed the typo in question. Make sure `jquery-ui-rails` is in the `Gemfile.lock` file; if it is not present, running `bundle install` will fix the problem.

Comment: @Prakash Murthy jquery-ui-rails (4.2.1) is there in Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using gem `'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'` You must include `//= require jquery.ui.all` in js and `*= require jquery.ui.all` in css instead of `//= require jquery.ui` & `*= require jquery.ui`

Because `//= require jquery.ui` & `*= require jquery.ui` are present after `'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.0'` this is not present in `'jquery-ui-rails'` 4.x.x version.

See more document changes [here for 4.x.x](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails/tree/v4.2.1) and [here for 5.x.x](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails/tree/v5.0.0)